# .htaccess rewriterule for username like facebook

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am utilising following code for my current application

```
RewriteBase /

#for profile display
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&option=$2&source=$3 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1&option=$2 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [QSA]

#for hiding.php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

What this will do is, it will treat URL `www.domain.com/user/johndoe/photos/photoid-123` as `www.domain.com/profile.php?username=johndoe&option=photos&source=photoid-123`

Now, what I want to do is to remove /user/ part from the url and keep it like `www.domain.com/johndoe/photos/photoid-123`

I have tried modifying rewrite rule like `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/....` OR `RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/....` OR `RewriteRule ([^/]+)/....`, but it is giving me 500 Error

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have it this way:

DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

```
#ignore files and directories from rewrites
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&option=$2&source=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1&option=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [QSA,L]

#for hiding.php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It's working but it also treating existing filenames as GET value.

Comment: Existing filenames will be ignored if you've used these rules as is (check my first rule to ignore files/directories)

Comment: Aha. Got it. I just moved `#for hiding.php extension` code at the top. But, will that cause any problem in any case?

Comment: and how to go to index.php if value is empty?

Comment: You can use `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php` for that. See updated code.